# Broken boot-splash arch linux

Tags: boot, arch-linux, kernel

Does anyone know why systems sometimes make broken images on boot? I had same problem when I've upgraded my kernel on Ubuntu. Now this problem appears on my Arch laptop as well (fresh install and update)

Changing GRUB-settings doesn't help at all.

[image: broken boot-splash arch linux]

Comment: I had the same issue a few years back with Ubuntu, try to tinker with the "vga=xyz" argument of the kernel command line and/or the "set gfxpayload" and "set gfxmode" in GRUB. You can directly edit these values from GRUB by pressing "e" at the GRUB menu.

Comment: Thank for your comment @AndréDaniel. gfxpayload is already set to "keep". Adding "set gfxmode=1380x768" (screen resolution) did nothing